# Google App Engine WebApp2 template not working

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

I am learning Google App Engine, and have started with WebApp2 framework + Jinja2 template.

I have written the following code:

**Main.py**

```
import webapp2
import os
import jinja2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import ndb



template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir))



class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self, write(self.render_str(template, **kw))


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello world!')


class PageOne(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('pageone.html')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler),('/pageone', PageOne)], debug=True)
```

**app.yaml**

```
application: tbapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"

- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

There is also a pageone.html HTML file in templates folder.

Now, when I run the files, the main page is showing *Hello world!*. But, when I run http://localhost:8080/pageone..... it returns the following error..

```
 File "E:\gae_apps\tbapp\tbapp\main.py", line 50, in get
    self.render('pageone.html')
  File "E:\gae_apps\tbapp\tbapp\main.py", line 40, in render
    self, write(self.render_str(template, **kw))
NameError: global name 'write' is not defined
```

Can anyone please guide me, what am In doing wrong. I am not able to figure out. TIA

Comment: `self, write` should be `self.write`

Comment: @Amber I am so grateful to you for that... Thanks a ton!... and that was really dumb on my part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Amber pointed out, you have a typo in your `Handler`'s `render` method.

Replace

```
def render(self, template, **kw):
    self, write(self.render_str(template, **kw))
```

With

```
def render(self, template, **kw):
    self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))
```

The error message does give you a hint

`NameError: global name 'write' is not defined`